# POST request not returning Allow-Origin header

Tags: node.js, express, cors, aws-lambda, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a POST request on a AWS lambda that has cors enabled and I using the cors package in the API.
Then I make a POST request with fetch but I get this error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The cors package was not supposed to take tare of this or I need to do some additional configuration?

api.js

```
import { json, urlencoded } from 'body-parser'
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'

import recipe from './routes/recipe'
import login from './routes/login'
import unit from './routes/unit'

const app = express()

app.use(cors()) // enabling cors
app.use(json())
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use('/recipes', recipe)
app.use('/login', login)
app.use('/units', unit)
```

request.js

```
const params = { 'POST', body, mode: 'cors' }
return await (await fetch(baseURL + endpoint, params)).json()
```

recipe.js

```
import { Router } from 'express'
const router = Router()

router.post('/', async ({ body }, res) => {
  // save recipe in database
  res.json(recipeId)
})

export default router
```

full source code - api: https://github.com/EliasBrothers/zanzas-recipes-api/tree/beta-develop
frontend - https://github.com/EliasBrothers/zanzas-recipes-web/tree/develop

Comment: Your cors configuration seems all right. I was wondering where the *request.js* running? Client side or AWS lambda?

Comment: is running on lambda, I use claudiajs to deploy on aws

Comment: Is the same project with **api.js**? If so, the issue is CORS settings should be reconfigured  on server side, which means where **baseURL** runs on.

Comment: the api.js is running on lambda, and request is running locally. in the aws console I enabled cors in this api

Comment: Is Cors is enabled at ApiGateway? I mean is there OPTIONS method added as a mock request in your resource?

Comment: Yes, it's enabled. But how do I make a options mock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work by updating the packages from the project and changing the request

```
 const stringifiedBody = JSON.stringify(body) // added
  const params = {
    method,
    body: stringifiedBody,
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: { // added
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a copying error, you didn't specify the fetch method **POST** in right way. Sometimes a **Not Found** page will also be recognized as **CORS** problem. Have you tried to normalize your fetch parameters?

```
params = {
 method: 'POST',
 body: body,
 mode:'cors'
}
```

Comment: Too bad, have you tested the cors settings on local development environment? Does it work?

Comment: yes, I have another endpoint that I make a GET request and the response has the header 'Allow-Origin'

Comment: From the [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) of **CORS** middle-ware, the cors configurations also could be located at every route likes recipe, login or unit. Have you checked whether there are settings be covered?

Comment: Theo docs said that app.use(cors) would be enough to make all routes cors-enabled. I also tried using router.use(cors) inside recipes, but didn't work.

Comment: https://github.com/EliasBrothers/zanzas-recipes-web/tree/develop?files=1 this is the frontend

Comment: I found some wired code, fell free to tell me if there is any misunderstanding. You got an **app.js** file, but never reference the **api.js**. So I made some changes in **app.js**, replace `var app = require('express')()` with `var app = require('./api');` and then seems all works fine.  PS, I am testing on **Develop** branch, you guys missing a **show-message-handler.js** on git.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to 'git push' my latest code, now it's updated, thanks for your time!